# Dual NIC for reverse NAT access

Tags: iptables, traceroute

Need help with this goal:

```
Internet
    <-- TP_LINK Router(192.168.0.1)
        <-- PC1(eth0:192.168.0.8)
        <-- PC2(eth0:192.168.0.81)
```

When I use cable to connect PC2 eth1 to PC3 eth0, and configure PC2 eth1 IPV4 settings to "shared to other computers", then PC2 and PC3 get below IPs:

```
    PC2(eth1:10.42.0.1)
        <-- PC3(eth0: 10.42.0.169)
```

Now I want to do something on route or iptables so that I can "ping 10.42.0.169" on PC1.

Is this possible? Below is what I've tried:

- Configure TP_LINK Router's static route table: 10.42.0.0(target) - 255.255.255.0(netmask) - 192.168.0.81(gateway).

Now I get result on PC1:

```
$ traceroute 10.42.0.169
traceroute to 10.42.0.169 (10.42.0.169), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  4.018 ms  0.905 ms  0.768 ms
2  ay11 (192.168.0.81)  1.140 ms  1.273 ms  1.482 ms
3  ay11 (192.168.0.81)  1.104 ms  1.041 ms  1.127 ms
```

We can see that if PC2 can forward packets to 10.42.0.0/24, maybe everything will be perfect?

Here is the configurations on PC2:

```
$ route
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.0.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1

$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for mlhch: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.42.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/24         anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

What should I do with route or iptables?

Thanks!

Comment: Shared connections are NATed. Is there a reason for not using a bridge?

Comment: I'm just experimenting and learning and not very good at it. Yes, bridge would be better, but that will be another story.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set on `PC2` The first thing to do is do enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your efforts.

For /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward, it was already "1" and I had configured net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf

I executed your iptables commands, they just append below 2 lines in Chain FORWARD section:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Then no miracle happens. But that make me notice the 2 REJECT lines

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I delete them and everything work perfectly! In fact I also delete the newly added lines, and only keep 1 "ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere" line.